# What's the best way to attach multiple files to a entity on creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

This is more so a question/best practice question than an issue. I currently have two pieces of code, one that creates an entity, and one to upload a file using Dropzone.js. The files are uploaded before the user creates the entity. I'm wondering, what exactly is the best way to attach the files in the system to the entity?

Right now, I'm posting back a "file ID", which is a GUID and then appending it to a comma-separated string in the entities form. When the entity is created, I'm going out and looking for that file and creating the association then. This seems kinda hacky and not right though... Plus I'd have to create some kind of cleanup process in case the user attaches files but ends up not creating the entity.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a special temporary file upload holder entity when the user starts uploading the first file, and having all subsequent uploads get attached to that temporary entity. Once the user attempts to create the real entity, you can associate it with all those files and delete the temporary entity.

You'll want to implement a cleanup job that runs every so often to clear out any old instances of these temporary file upload entities that may have been orphaned when the user failed to complete the entity creation process.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So when the temporary holder is created, how would you attach it to the main entity? Pass back a value and update a hidden field in the entities form? Or is that still kinda hacky? I know that would probably work but I want to know what the "best practice" would be for this scenario.

Comment: @Calvin: I think passing back a value and associating it with your creation form is a perfectly good approach. It associates the information with the context of the creation form, which represents the thing you're planning to create in the long run. What you *wouldn't* want to do is associate it with the user's session or something. The temporary entity probably should have the current user ID associated with it, though, so you can do some basic server-side checks to ensure users don't try to hijack each other's uploaded files.